# How to use JQuery inputmask on input text box with vue binding?

Tags: jquery, vue.js, jquery-inputmask

I am trying use JQuery inputmask on input text box which has vue js binding, but input text gets cleared when ever I change the drop down in that page, is there any best practice to use inputmask with vue js?
Also I don't want mask chars to apparent in my binding model value.

In the html code:

```
 <input asp-for="PrimaryPhone" v-model="Model.primaryPhone" class="form- 
   control js-form-element viewcomponent-modal-field-box tel" aria-describedby="PrimaryPhoneInput">
```

In the javascript:

```
$('input:text.tel').inputmask('(999) 999-9999', { placeholder: ""});
```

Comment: Why do you use jQuery with VueJS? Using jQuery with VueJS is not recommended and can have some undesirable effects, specially when jQuery modify the DOM. Maybe try to do it using ES6 or vanilla JS

Answer (score 1):

Posting this answer on a very old question, but it may help someone.

In VueJs 3 Composition API you can use `onUpdated` lifecycle hook like below and it should work!

```
onUpdated(() => {
    $('input:text.tel').inputmask('(999) 999-9999', { placeholder: ""});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To made it simpler try to use [this v-mask module of Vue](https://github.com/probil/v-mask)

Just import it as the doc say and then just specify your mask on your input like that

```
<input asp-for="PrimaryPhone" v-model="Model.primaryPhone" class="form-control js-form-element viewcomponent-modal-field-box tel" aria-describedby="PrimaryPhoneInput" v-mask="'(###) ###-####'">
```